# File used by another process c#

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I am working in a WPF application, i want to create an XML file and load it at the same time in a Window.
For now my code work fine, but when i want to load the created file in the Window it tells me that the File used by another process.
Here is my code

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
        var timestamp = "" + now.Hour + now.Minute + now.Second;
        string sb = "test";
        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        File.WriteAllText(string.Format("{0}\\{1}.xml", path, timestamp), sb);
        File.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\\{1}.xml", path, timestamp));


        XmlDocument XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            XMLdoc.Load(string.Format("{0}\\{1}.biml", path, timestamp));
        }
        catch (XmlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The XML file is invalid");
            return;
        }


        vXMLViwer.xmlDocument = XMLdoc;
```

Comment: You probably mean to use `AppendAllText` instead of `AppendText`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File.AppendText` would open the file and return a stream that you can use to append data. Since you are not using the return value of such method, this means that you will not close the stream until the garbage collector decides to kick in later.

It is not clear what you are trying to do with `File.AppendText` (maybe you don't even need it?). But if you want to open the file, append some text, and then close it, then you should use [`File.AppendAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.